# RDLC image not show by set report parameter

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rdlc, report-viewer2010

I am working with RDLC Report in 2010

I want to bind image from external source

```
ReportParameter rpara = new ReportParameter("rpt1", "D:\\Projects\\Image\\logo.jpg");
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { rpara });
```

I also set all the property of rdlc design like 
add parameter `rpt1` in report data window 
add new image in body part then set image property to `external` and select report parameter

everything okay but still I am not able to get image on my report viewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this way

```
string imagepath = "File:///" + "C:\\image.jpg";
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
ReportParameter[] param = new ReportParameter[1];
param[0] = new ReportParameter("Path", imagepath);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(param);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```